# how to access on-premise network drive through azure devops pipeline using self hosted agents (hosted on AKS)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

We are using Azure Devops for CICD pipeline and using self hosted agents which are hosted on AKS.
We have scenario where our pipeline needs to run a ps script on a on-premises server or in other words, the pipeline needs to copy some build artifacts on a network share drive (which is on-premise server)
Currently using linux based agent , but if someone have some idea on how to achieve this scenario on linux or windows then it can be helpful.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is run a self-hosted build agent on premise which has connectivity to the network share. You can have the on-prem step run by the on-prem agent and have it publish the artifact which can then be used by the existing AKS agents for example.

Otherwise you need some network connectivity between the AKS cluster and the on-prem network share, either by VPN or Expressroute.